# Selenium Python copy, paste img src

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

right now I have made this -

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,'.thumbnail-2d-container img')))
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,'.thumbnail-2d-container img').get_attribute('src')
driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[1])
time.sleep(2)
driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div[3]/div[1]/div[3]/form/div/div/div[2]/div/div[6]/div[2]/div/table[2]/tbody/tr/td[1]/input').click()
driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div[3]/div[1]/div[3]/form/div/div/div[2]/div/div[6]/div[2]/div/table[2]/tbody/tr/td[1]/input').send_keys(Keys.CONTROL,'v')
time.sleep(500)
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME,'thumbnail-2d-container carousel-item carousel-item-active')))
driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME,'thumbnail-2d-container carousel-item carousel-item-active').get_attribute('src')
driver.close()
```

Now it goes to Roblox goes to a game and I want to copy the first image from the slider. Link to a game - [Defence Tycoon](https://www.roblox.com/games/6661139142/ARMY-Military-Defense-Tycoon)

So I have this line of code `driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME,'thumbnail-2d-container carousel-item carousel-item-active').get_attribute('src')` it seems like it doesn't copy the src because when I paste it, it just pastes something from my clipboard

I need it so it can copy the image from any game, all games have the same img class - `thumbnail-2d-container carousel-item carousel-item-active`

Answer (score 0):

Ohh all I had to do was

```
src = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,'.thumbnail-2d-container img').get_attribute('src')
```

then

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div[3]/div[1]/div[3]/form/div/div/div[2]/div/div[6]/div[2]/div/table[2]/tbody/tr/td[1]/input').send_keys(src)
```

Comment: Using absolute xpath is not a great idea. If you see the DOM, there are attributes which you can use to further refine the code.